# What is the best way to return multiple data frames from a loop?

Tags: python, dataframe

so i have a function that returns an table from a SQL database but i'm wondering how to go about it the best way, currently this is what i have done but i feel like some of the code has been repeated so its not the best dry principle

```
class DataExtractor:
    def extract_rds_table(engine, table_name: Union[str, list]):
        """
        Extracts the table from the engine and reads it into a pandas Dataframe then returns it
        Once given multiple table names as input, it will return a dictionary Key, Value pairs
        of table_name and dataframe

        Parameters
            input: Engine (Sqlalchemy.engine)
            input: Table/Tables (str | list)
            Output: Pandas Dataframe of the table in question/ Dictionary of dataframes
        
        """
        if(type(table_name) == str):
            pandas_table_extracted = pd.read_sql_table(f'{table_name}', engine)
            return pandas_table_extracted
        elif(type(table_name) == list):
            stored_table_names_and_data = {}
            for table in table_name:
                pandas_table_extracted = pd.read_sql_table(f'{table}', engine)
                stored_table_names_and_data[f'{table}'] = pandas_table_extracted
            return stored_table_names_and_data
```

Comment: You could make an generator using `yield`

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, explicitly remap the input to a known format and always return a dict:

```
class DataExtractor:
    def extract_rds_table(engine, table_name: Union[str, list]) -> dict:
        """
        Extracts the table from the engine and reads it into a pandas Dataframe then returns it
        Once given multiple table names as input, it will return a dictionary Key, Value pairs
        of table_name and dataframe

        Parameters
        input: Engine (Sqlalchemy.engine)
        input: Table/Tables (str | list)
        Output: Dictionary of dataframes
        """

        if type(table_name) == str:
            table_list = [table_name]
        elif type(table_name) in (list, set, tuple):
            table_list = list(table_name)
        else:
            raise ValueError(f'Unknown table name input type {type(table_name)}.')

        stored_table_names_and_data = {}
        for table in table_name:
            pandas_table_extracted = pd.read_sql_table(f'{table}', engine)
            stored_table_names_and_data[f'{table}'] = pandas_table_extracted
        return stored_table_names_and_data
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not that bad, except for you can avoid extra variables and iterative dict assignment:

```
class DataExtractor:
    def extract_rds_table(engine, table_name: Union[str, list]):
        """
        Extracts the table from the engine and reads it into a pandas Dataframe then returns it
        Once given multiple table names as input, it will return a dictionary Key, Value pairs
        of table_name and dataframe

        Parameters
            input: Engine (Sqlalchemy.engine)
            input: Table/Tables (str | list)
            Output: Pandas Dataframe of the table in question/ Dictionary of dataframes

        """
        if (type(table_name) == str):
            return pd.read_sql_table(f'{table_name}', engine)
        elif (type(table_name) == list):
            return dict((table, pd.read_sql_table(f'{table}', engine)) 
                        for table in table_name)
```